# Drupal Views + Multiple CiviCRM relationships of same type

Tags: drupal-views, relationships

I see many stack exchange questions about views & relationships but none like this.

A person may attend many schools in his/her lifetime.

Contact A "is a student at" Contact B (college, active relationship)

Contact A "is a student at" Contact C (high school, expired relationship)

Contact A "is a student at" Contact D (middle school, expired relationship)

I need a view that displays all Organization names of schools where the contact type is "is a student at" whether active or not.

This screen recording may better explain and shows my progress thus far: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_gkXbYn-Kdg8G-8JDfbz7J96ELvt_Gon/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

It appears the View you are using is starting from the entity CiviCRM Relationship. This is unusual in my experience. I would be building a View based on Contacts and then adding the Related Contacts by using the View Relationships to pull them in.